# Excel: Summing values within a certain date range (> start date and < Finish date)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function, date-time

How do I include a 'Between these dates' criteria inside a SUMPRODUCT?

```
=Sumproduct((RangeName=Cell A1)*(RangeDate=Between 01/03/10 and 31/03/10)*(RangeCost))
```

What's the way to manage dates (between) in a sum product?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help get you started. You'll need to adjust your ranges to fit your data

- A1 = Beginning Date
- A2 = Ending Date
- A4:A200 = Date column
- B4:B200 = Cost column

  =SUMPRODUCT(--(INT($A$4:$A$200)>=$A$1),--(INT($A$4:$A$200)<=$A$2),--($B$4:$B$200))

Comment: Thanks. I'm finding the results slightly predictable. It looks like  it's not taking any notice of the >= or <= part of the formula. I'm still working on it.

Comment: IN the end I cheated. I made another column and used Concatenate((Year($A4),(Month($A4)) that gave me my defined date range (the month) and then pointed my sumproduct at that column rather than the one we were trying to do above.

This isn't an answer, but just to say I worked around it rather than solved it. It would be nice to know how it could be done the legitimate way though ;)

Comment: Mike, it sounds like at least one of your dates is not a true date at all, but some text that looks like a date.